In Django, combining and ordering counts across two model fields
I have these two simplified models, representing people and letters that have been sent and received by those people:
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

class Letter(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=False, related_name="letters_sent")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=False, related_name="letters_received")

I want to display a list of Persons ordered by how many times they've sent or received any letters.
I started doing this very laboriously, but figure there must be a simpler way.
e.g., this gets the Person IDs and counts of how many times they've sent a Letter:
senders = (
    Letter.objects.order_by()
    .values(person_id=F("sender"))
    .annotate(count=Count("pk"))
    .distinct()
)

I can do the same for recipients.
Then combine the two into a single list/dict, adding the counts together.
Sort that.
Then inflate that data with the actual Person objects, and pass that to the template.
But I feel there must be a less laborious way, starting, I think, with a single query to get the combined sent + received counts.

You should be able to count all the letters and annotate that onto the person queryset. That will be less laborious in terms of written Django code (though I couldn't say if it'd be less laborious for the database or not).
In any case, this ought to be in the right neighborhood for what I'm describing:
queryset = Person.objects.annotate(
    letter_count=(
        Count('letters_sent', distinct=True) + Count('letters_received', distinct=True))
    )
).order_by('-letter_count', 'name')

distinct=True to make sure we're not double-counting objects.
From my test run:
In [1]: from test.models import Person, Letter

In [2]: from django.db.models import Count

In [3]: p1 = Person.objects.get(name="John")

In [4]: p2 = Person.objects.get(name="Mary")

In [5]: p3 = Person.objects.get(name="Alex")

In [6]: Letter.objects.filter(sender=p1).count()
Out[6]: 4

In [7]: Letter.objects.filter(recipient=p1).count()
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: queryset = Person.objects.annotate(letter_count=(Count('letters_sent', distinct=True) + Count('letters_received', distinct=True))).order_by('-letter_count', 'name')

In [9]: queryset.first().letter_count
Out[9]: 6

In [10]: Letter.objects.filter(recipient=p3).count()
Out[10]: 1

In [11]: Letter.objects.filter(sender=p3).count()
Out[11]: 2

In [12]: queryset.last().letter_count
Out[12]: 3

In [13]: from django.db.models import Q, F

In [14]: Letter.objects.filter(Q(sender=p1) | Q(recipient=p1)).count()
Out[14]: 6

In [15]: Letter.objects.filter(Q(sender=p3) | Q(recipient=p3)).count()
Out[15]: 3

In [16]: Letter.objects.filter(Q(sender=p2) | Q(recipient=p2)).count()
Out[16]: 5


The sender and recipient fields both have related_name set (now added to my example code), which is maybe why I get "Cannot resolve keyword 'letter_set' into field." when I try this?

That is correct. But with the added related_name fields, the query becomes simpler yet - answer updated.

Ah, yes that is simpler! However, using that I'm getting errors like column "Person.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. If I add values('id'). before annotate then it works, but of course I only get a dict for each result, not the Person object.

Add name to order_by and see if that gets you anywhere. Answer reflects this now, too.

It doesn't. Also I've just noticed the counts are wrong. e.g. one Person has person.letters_sent.count() as 20, and person.letters_received.count() as 28. But when doing this query (with values('id')) it gets a letter_count of 1120.

order_by() worked for me, I don't see any of the errors you mentioned. The count was off because my solution counting instances more than once. Updated again with a fix for that as well, and a test run to double-check the results.

Thank you for your efforts! I can see it should work, I'm guessing there's just something up with my database beyond my simple example here. Marking as correct.
